# Displaying columns as rows in a complex Select statement - sql

Tags: sql-server, select, cross-apply

I have two tables (a base table and a data table) which I am merging using OUTER APPLY to get the result.

`tblBase` looks like this:

```
+------+------+
| IDnu | Name |
+------+------+
|  1   | abc  |
|  2   | cde  |
|  3   | efg  |
|  4   | rfl  |
+------+------+
```

`tblData` is this:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| IDNu | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | ProductType |
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
|    1 |     10 |     15 |     20 | Old         |
|    2 |     10 |     20 |     30 | Refurbished |
|    3 |     20 |     30 |     40 | New         |
|    1 |     20 |     15 |     20 | New         |
|    2 |     20 |     10 |     30 | Old         |
+------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

My current query which calculates the `tblData` based on few criteria is as below:

```
Select IDNu, Name, t2.PNew, t2.POld FROM tblBase as t1
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT
  SUM (CASE WHEN ProductType = 'New' THEN Price1 + Price2 ELSE 0 END) AS PNew, 
  SUM (CASE WHEN ProductType = 'Old' THEN Price2 + Price3 ELSE 0 END) AS POld
FROM tblData
WHERE IDNu = t1.IDNu
GROUP BY IDNu
) t2
```

The above query results in:

```
+------+------------+------+------+
| IDNu |    Name    | PNew | POld |
+------+------------+------+------+
|    1 | abc        | 35   | 35   |
|    2 | cde        | 0    | 40   |
|    3 | efg        | 50   | 0    |
|    4 | rfl        | NULL | NULL |
+------+------------+------+------+
```

**Now my question is, instead of showing PNew and POld in two columns, show them in rows?** Like this:

```
+------+------------+-------------+-------+
| IDNu |    Name    | ProductType | Price |
+------+------------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | abc        | PNew        | 35    |
|    2 | cde        | PNew        | 0     |
|    3 | efg        | PNew        | 50    |
|    4 | rfl        | PNew        | NULL  |
|    1 | abc        | POld        | 35    |
|    2 | cde        | POld        | 40    |
|    3 | efg        | POld        | 0     |
|    4 | rfl        | POld        | NULL  |
+------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: This is not mysql. This is TSQL.. Stackoverflow automatically tagged it as 'mysql', not sure why.

Comment: Sorry, I know why. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to ask questions related to SQL, please consult this article: [*How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum*](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT tblBase.*, 'PNew' as ProductType, tblData.Price1 + tblData.Price2 as Price
 FROM tblBase left join `tblData`
 On tblBase.IDnu = tblData.IDnu AND tblData.ProductType = 'New' 
UNION ALL
SELECT tblBase.*, 'POld' as ProductType, tblData.Price3 + tblData.Price2 as Price
 FROM tblBase left join `tblData`
 On tblBase.IDnu = tblData.IDnu AND tblData.ProductType = 'Old'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select b.IDNu, b.Name, pt.ProductType, d.Price
from
    tblBase as b cross join (select 'New' ProductType union all select 'Old') pt
    left outer join
    (
        select
            ProductType,
            sum(case ProductType
                    when 'New' then Price1 + Price2
                    when 'Old' then Price2 + Price3 end) as Price
        from tblData
        where ProductType in ('New', 'Old') /* not strictly necessary but maybe faster */
        group by IDNu, ProductType
    ) d
        on d.IDNu = p.IDNu and d.ProductType = pt.ProductType
order by b.IDNu, pt.ProductType
```

or ...

```
select
    b.IDNu, b.Name, pt.ProductType,
    sum(case pt.ProductType
            when 'New' then d.Price1 + d.Price2
            when 'Old' then d.Price2 + d.Price3 end) as Price
from
    tblBase as b
    cross join
    (select 'New' ProductType union all select 'Old') pt
    left outer join
    tblData d on d.IDNu = p.IDNu and d.ProductType = pt.ProductType
group by b.IDNu, pt.ProductType
order by b.IDNu, pt.ProductType
```

In your output you've mixed some zero and null outputs where there's no data. Of course the normal way to translate these nulls is to use `coalesce()`. Also you have "PNew" and "POld" as your output value but I'm not sure that was intentional. A simple `case` will handle those in the output `select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to unpivot in your outer applied table:

```
Select 
    IDNu,Name,t2.ProductType,t2.Price
FROM 
    tblBase as t1
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT ProductType='New',SUM(Price1+Price2) AS Price
        FROM tblData
        WHERE IDNu=t1.IDNu AND ProductType='New'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ProductType='Old',SUM(Price2+Price3) AS Price
        FROM tblData
        WHERE IDNu=t1.IDNu AND ProductType='Old'
    ) t2
```